# Can't add resources to jar in maven

Tags: java, swing, maven, jar, pom.xml

This is my problem: I have a Maven project that is using a Swing library and it is a GUI app which I  want to include a resources (images and one config.properties file) in my jar file.

Here is my `pom.xml` code:

```
  <build>
    <resources>

      <resource>

        <directory>${basedir}/resource</directory>

            <includes>
                <include>**/*.png</include>
            </includes>

        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>

      </resource>

      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/config</directory>

        <includes>
            <include>config.properties</include>
        </includes>

        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>

      <resource>
        <directory>.settings</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>


    </resources>



    <plugins>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
         <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>bis.debug.mode.ui.MainBISDebugMode</mainClass>
            </manifest>
         </archive>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>


  </build>
</project>
```

and here is my structure to my project:

[image: Project structure]

I included directories as it seen in the pom.xml and the files in it and still doesn't included in jar file and it doesn't see images on the GUI app. When I run the program as Java application everything is fine.

Is it possible to be something wrong in my code? How I can fix the problem?

Comment: What happened here?

Comment: Please, don't destroy your own posts. It will be inevitably rolled back

Comment: No i didn't , sorry about the problem that happened

Answer (score 4):

You need only to put your config file in `src/main/resources` and no need to add resources in `pom.xml` because `src/main/resources` is the maven's default  resources folder

Comment: i did it but again no change happened

Comment: be sure that you did the `mvn clean install`

Comment: Again no difference

Comment: take a look at this [link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: Okay the problem isn't in the maven pom.xml. The problem was in the code because i must get the file like this example:  InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fileName");

Comment: Yes no problem with your pom.xml just you dont realy need  resources plugin in your case